# What is the best way to iterate over multiple lists at once?

Tags: python

Let's say I have two or more lists of same length. What's a good way to iterate through them?

`a`, `b` are the lists.

```
 for i, ele in enumerate(a):
    print ele, b[i]
```

or

```
for i in range(len(a)):
   print a[i], b[i]
```

or is there any variant I am missing?

Is there any particular advantages of using one over other?

Answer (score 144, accepted):

The usual way is to use [`zip()`](http://docs.python.org//library/functions.html#zip):

```
for x, y in zip(a, b):
    # x is from a, y is from b
```

This will stop when the shorter of the two iterables `a` and `b` is exhausted.  Also worth noting: [`itertools.izip()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) (Python 2 only) and [`itertools.izip_longest()`](http://docs.python.org//library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) (`itertools.zip_longest()` in Python 3).

Comment: Beat me to it.  It may be worth noting that Python 3's `zip` *is* `izip`.  Also, there's no `zip_longest` but `map(None, a, b)` can do.

Comment: @ephemient: The latter only on Python 2, again.  On Python 3, this will stop on the shortest sequence.  And `izip_longest()` is called `zip_longest()` on Python 3…

Comment: @SvenMarnach But zip stops when one of the 2 lists end , What if I want to iterate to the max length in python3

Comment: @Abhay That is actually answered above as well – you need to use `iterloos.zip_longest()`.

Answer (score 16):

You can use `zip`:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> for x, y in zip(a, b):
...   print x, y
... 
1 a
2 b
3 c
```