# Python use 2 lists in 1 loop

Tags: python

I have the below code which has the list `r3000`, a list of links to save as html.

Is it possible to save the files with different names using a separate list?

For example, `r3000` would include the link ('http://research.investors.com/quotes/nyse-agilent-technologies-inc-a.htm?fromsearch=1') then have another list called `r3000sym` that is `['a','','',...]`. Then file would be saved as `a.html`.

```
import time
import urllib2
from urllib2 import urlopen

r3000 = ['http://research.investors.com/quotes/nyse-agilent-technologies-inc-a.htm?fromsearch=1',
         'http://research.investors.com/quotes/nyse-alcoa-inc-aa.htm?fromsearch=1',
         'http://research.investors.com/quotes/nasdaq-american-airlines-group-aal.htm?fromsearch=1',
         'http://research.investors.com/quotes/amex-altisource-asset-mgmt-aamc.htm?fromsearch=1',
         'http://research.investors.com/quotes/nyse-aarons-inc-aan.htm?fromsearch=1',
         'http://research.investors.com/quotes/nasdaq-applied-optoelectronics-aaoi.htm?fromsearch=1',
         'http://research.investors.com/quotes/nasdaq-a-a-o-n-inc-aaon.htm?fromsearch=1',
         'http://research.investors.com/quotes/nyse-advance-auto-parts-inc-aap.htm?fromsearch=1']

def yahooKeyStats(stock):
    try:
        site= stock
        hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
        req = urllib2.Request(site,headers=hdr)
        page = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()


        dataFile = 'a.html'
        f = open(dataFile,'a')
        f.write(page)
        f.close()

        print 'Done',stock

    except Exception,e:
        print str(e)


for eachStock in r3000:
    yahooKeyStats(eachStock)
```

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for zip().

Comment: You can loop over two lists using `zip()`

Answer (score 2):

`itertools` is what you are looking for:

```
import itertools
for it1,it2 in itertools.izip(list1,list2):
    print(it1,it2)
```

Zip takes 2 lists and makes tupled list out of them, `itertools` allows you to iterate at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Use a two-tuple to store url and name in one list:

```
import time
import urllib2
from urllib2 import urlopen

r3000 = [
    ('a.html', 'http://research.investors.com/quotes/nyse-agilent-technologies-inc-a.htm?fromsearch=1'),
    ('b.html', 'http://research.investors.com/quotes/nyse-alcoa-inc-aa.htm?fromsearch=1'),
]

def yahooKeyStats(name, stock):
    try:
        site= stock
        hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
        req = urllib2.Request(site,headers=hdr)
        page = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()

        with open(name,'a') as f:
            f.write(page)

        print 'Done',stock

    except Exception,e:
        print str(e)


for name, stock in r3000:
    yahooKeyStats(name, stock)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for the zip() function. It creates an iterable of tuples based on the two lists given, which you can assign as a local loops variable. see: [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10080379/better-way-to-iterate-two-multiple-lists-at-once)