# Python, solver method or optimization of current code?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, iterator, solver

I am trying to add more data to the matrices to analyze and solve for the , but as it stands currently it is performing the brute operation, it exceeds python's limits if I add another column to the analysis. Is there a solver method availalbe that would find a similar result rather than having to brute through combinations? The sample.csv is also listed below. Thanks for any advice.

```
import csv
import itertools as it
import numpy as np

C = 2618.08
B = 933.15
A = 932.37
adjust = 1


D = csv.reader(open('sample.csv'))

float_ABC = []
OUT = np.zeros((3, 9)) - 100

for row in D:
        float_ABC.append([str(x) for x in row])

float_ABC = float_ABC.astype(np.float)

Alpha=float_ABC[:, [0,3,6,9,12,15]]
Beta=float_ABC[:, [2,5,8,11,14,17]]
Phi=float_ABC[:, [1,4,7,10,13,16]]

plines1 = it.product(Alpha[0],Alpha[1],Alpha[2],Alpha[3],
                     Alpha[4],Alpha[5],Alpha[6],Alpha[7],
                     Alpha[8])

plines2 = it.product(Beta[0],Beta[1],Beta[2],Beta[3],
                     Beta[4],Beta[5],Beta[6],Beta[7],
                     Beta[8])

plines3 = it.product(Phi[0],Phi[1],Phi[2],Phi[3],
                     Phi[4],Phi[5],Phi[6],Phi[7],
                     Phi[8])


for count in range(0,6**9):
    sumA = next(plines1)
    sumB = next(plines2)
    sumC = next(plines3)

    if  (sum(sumC)+B)/(sum(sumA)+C) <= (B+adjust)/(C) and \
        (sum(sumC)+B)/(sum(sumA)+C) >= (B+adjust-10)/(C) and \
        (sum(sumB)+A)/(sum(sumA)+C) > (sum(OUT[2])+A)/(sum(OUT[0])+C):
        print("#",count,"- new option found!")
        OUT = np.vstack((sumA,sumC,sumB))
```

and sample.csv:

```
13.4,-18.81,-24.75,5.82,-8.21,-10.8,0,0,0,3.3,1.56,2.05,-2.1,5.36,7.05,2.6,5.65,7.44
0,-11.01,-14.49,0,-4.87,-6.41,0,0,0,0.6,2.24,2.95,1,4,5.26,1.7,2.73,3.59
0,-40.74,-53.6,0,-17.86,-23.5,0,0,0,3.5,6.53,8.59,2.9,9.36,12.31,1.9,2.61,3.44
1000,-1000,-1000,0,0,0,20.76,21.78,15.66,18.48,23.44,16.96,27.72,26.46,19.92,32.28,29.58,23.08
1000,-1000,-1000,-2.28,-6.12,-4.16,-2.28,-2.53,-1.73,0,0,0,1.92,-1.85,-1.26,1.08,-1.27,-0.86
1000,-1000,-1000,0,0,0,6.78,7.38,5.07,6.66,8.93,6.14,8.46,8.41,5.78,9.42,10.37,7.14
1000,-1000,-1000,0,0,0,28.8,34.28,27.86,37.2,39.64,33.32,45.6,42.76,36.63,54,45.88,40.03
1000,-1000,-1000,0,-4.95,-3.36,0,0,0,1.8,0.59,0.4,1.2,1.85,1.27,3.72,0.17,0.11
1000,-1000,-1000,0,0,0,27.6,19.3,13.71,32.76,23.68,17.15,37.8,20.56,14.71,22.56,27.58,21.06
```

Comment: what do you mean by "it exceeds python's limits"? What kind of error are you getting? I can suggest using `for count, (sumA,sumB,sumC) in enumerate(zip(plines1,plines2,plines3)):` and caching the result of `sum(sumA)+C` etc. since you recalculate it several times every iteration.

Comment: I would expect the above code to raise `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'astype'` on the line `float_ABC = float_ABC.astype(np.float)` since `float_ABC` is a list...

Comment: thanks @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen for the input - the line `for count, (sumA,sumB,sumC) in enumerate(zip(plines1,plines2,plines3)):` for some reason didn't connect in my brain and I had used that in other portions of my analysis - that does make sense. as to the float_ABC line, it had taken some of the entries as strings, and so it converts all to float objects - seems to work fine on my end. Much appreciated for the help on that though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is treating the question more like [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) then helping with algorithm.

First you can [iterate over all three `plines1` at the same time using zip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10080379/better-way-to-iterate-over-two-or-multiple-lists-at-once)

```
for sumA, sumB, sumC in zip(plines1, plines2, plines3):
    pass
```

but then to get a running count of the step you are on you can use `enumerate`:

```
for count, (sumA, sumB, sumC) in enumerate(zip(plines1, plines2, plines3)):
    pass
```

I also notice you recalculate `(B+adjust)/(C)` and `(B+adjust-10)/(C)` every iteration where neither are changed in the loop at all, so calculating them once before the loop instead of every iteration will definitely save you some execution time:

```
high_check = (B+adjust)/(C)
low_check = (B+adjust-10)/(C)

for count, (sumA, sumB, sumC) in enumerate(zip(plines1, plines2, plines3)):

    if ( low_check <= (sum(sumC)+B)/(sum(sumA)+C) <= high_check
          and <OTHER CHECK> ):
        ...
```

as well calculating `sum(sumA)` (and for sumB, sumC) over and over again is unecessarily costly, and somewhat confusing since `sumA` represents a tuple of values, it would make more sense to calculate the sums once and take the tuple `(sumA, sumB, sumC)` as one value called `matrix` (2d tuple is close enough)

```
for count, matrix in enumerate(zip(plines1, plines2, plines3)):
    sumA, sumB, sumC = map(sum, matrix)
    if ( low_check <= (sumC+B)/(sumA+C) <= high_check
          and <OTHER CHECK> ):
        ...
        OUT = np.vstack(matrix)
```

similarly only recalculating `(sum(OUT[2])+A)/(sum(OUT[0])+C)` only when `OUT` changes will reduce the execution time needed to recalculate unchanging values:

```
OUT_check = (sum(OUT[2])+A)/(sum(OUT[0])+C)

for ... in ...:

    if (  ...
          and (sumB+A)/(sumA+C) > OUT_check):
        ...
        OUT_check = (sum(OUT[2])+A)/(sum(OUT[0])+C)
```

so section of altered code would look like this:

```
plines1 = it.product(*Alpha) #star notation just unpacks all the elements into arguments
plines2 = it.product(*Beta)
plines3 = it.product(*Phi)

high_check = (B+adjust)/(C)
low_check = (B+adjust-10)/(C)
OUT_check = (sum(OUT[2])+A)/(sum(OUT[0])+C)

for count, matrix in enumerate(zip(plines1, plines2, plines3)):
    sumA, sumB, sumC = map(sum, matrix)
    if ( low_check <= (sumC+B)/(sumA+C) <= high_check
          and (sumB+A)/(sumA+C) > OUT_check):
        print("#",count,"- new option found!")
        OUT = np.vstack(matrix)
        OUT_check = (sum(OUT[2])+A)/(sum(OUT[0])+C)
```

Comment: I have changed the code to enumerate and cached the portions I can, saving some time in calculations given the current algorithm. My thanks to the optimization of the current algorithm. I suppose what I'm asking for improving time further - is if there is a solver algorithm that can further improve time so that I may add more columns of data to analyze? My ultimate goal is to have the sample.csv to import 15 items into each tuple, rather than 9. Would I be able to achieve this with the help of an algorithm of 'scipy.optimize' before iterating through all of the plines?

Comment: I haven't really used any of those sorts of functionalities so I won't be able to help on that front, sorry.