# How to index multiple item positions and get items from another list with those positions?

Tags: python

```
names = ['vik', 'zed', 'loren', 'tal', 'yam', 'jay', 'alex', 'gad', 'dan', 'hed']
cities = ['NY', 'NY', 'SA', 'TNY', 'LA', 'SA', 'SA', 'NY', 'SA', 'LA']
ages = ['28', '26', '26', '31', '28', '23', '29', '31', '27', '41']
```

How do I create a new list with names of all the people from SA?

I tried getting all 'SA' positions and then print the same positions that are in the names list,

```
pos = [i for i in range(len(names)) if cities[i] == 'SA']
print(names[pos])
```

Returns the following error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list
```

I've also attempted to loop over the positions in cities and then do pretty much the same but one by one, but i still wasn't able to put in a list

```
pos = [i for i in range(len(names)) if cities[i] == 'SA']
x = 1
for i in pos:
     x+=1
```

Comment: What output do you want exactly?

Comment: Meta dupe target: [what-is-the-best-way-to-iterate-over-multiple-lists-at-once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10080379/what-is-the-best-way-to-iterate-over-multiple-lists-at-once)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can zip the names ages and cities together then use a list comprehension to filter those by city

```
 [(a,b,c) for a,b,c in zip(names, cities, ages) if b == "SA"]
```

returns

```
[('loren', 'SA', '26'), ('jay', 'SA', '23'), ('alex', 'SA', '29'), ('dan', 'SA', '27')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Enumerate the list of cities so you get their index as well, and collect the names if the city matches:

```
names = ['vik', 'zed', 'loren', 'tal', 'yam', 'jay', 'alex', 'gad', 'dan', 'hed']
cities = ['NY', 'NY', 'SA', 'TNY', 'LA', 'SA', 'SA', 'NY', 'SA', 'LA'] 
  
print( [names[idx] for idx,c in enumerate(cities) if c == "SA"] )
```

Output:

```
['loren', 'jay', 'alex', 'dan']
```

See: [`enumerate` on python.org](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)

Answer (score 1):

*How do i create a new list with names of all the people from SA?*

Oneliner (but maybe the question is unclear) using `zip` and list comprehension with a filter

```
lst = [n for n, c in zip(names, cities) if c == 'SA']
print(lst)
```

Ouput:

```
['loren', 'jay', 'alex', 'dan']
```

**Explaination**

The oneliner is equivalent to:

```
lst = []
for name, city in zip(names, cities):
    if city == 'SA':
        lst.append(name)
print(lst)
```

`zip` iterates over the `names` and `cities` lists in parallel, producing tuples in the form *"(<a_name>, <a_city>)"*